# How to check array for possible divisors?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Creating the array, I am letting the user choose the length:

```
StartNum = scan.nextInt();
int[] NumBox = new int[StartNum];

 for (int i = 1; i < NumBox.length+1; i++)
  {NumBox[i - 1] = i;}

NumBox[0]=0;
```

Assuming there are other methods that can change cells in `NumBox` to 0, how would I use a for loop to check each cells in the array for any divisor? If there are no divisors for the cell in the array, it will then become a 0. For example, if the array is `[0,2,0,4,0,6,7,8,9]` `9,2 and 7` would become a `0`.

The code below is what I tired but didn't get far.

```
boolean NoDiv=false;
for (int a=1; a < NumBox.length+1; a++)
{
    a++
    for (int check=1; a < NumBox.length+1; check++)
    {
        if (NumBox[a-1]% check == 0 && NumBox[a-1] !=0) 
        {
            NumBox[a-1] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could improve the code by using variables starting by lower case letters, NumBox should be numBox. For loops between 1 and length + 1, removing one later from the index is a bit wierd aswell.

Comment: can you clarify some details ? yo usaid `if the array is [0,2,0,4,0,6,7,8,9] 9 ` - but isn't 9 a divisor of 9?

Comment: Java convention is to begin variable names, such as the name of the array, with lowercase letters.

Comment: This loop: for (int check=1; a < NumBox.length+1; check++) will never finish. nothing changes a. Always will be lower than NUmbox.length +1

Comment: Please clarify your goal here. In the given example of `[0,2,0,4,0,6,7,8,9]`, not only `9` has no divisors, but also `2` and `7`... And after you set `2` to `0` - `4` and `6` will also have no divisors... And after you set `4` to `0` - `8` will also have no divisors... In short, the entire array will be "zerofied".

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumBox.length; i++) {
    if (NumBox[i] == 0) continue;
    boolean hasDivisor = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (NumBox[j] == 0) continue;
        if (NumBox[i] % NumBox[j] == 0) {
            hasDivisor = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!hasDivisor) NumBox[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: `NumBox.Length` I guess that was a typo?

Comment: no, that part is correct in your code.  But the elements of the array have indices from 0 to NumBox.Length - 1 and if you refer to another index you get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.